# How to create parameters that accept any numeric type

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net when creating methods and properties I am creating methods using decimal parameters. There are other numeric types like short, long, double, etc.

Is there a simple way to create parameters that cover all numeric types in a single property/method without creating an overloaded property/method for each numeric type?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950697/is-it-possible-to-write-a-generic-function-in-net-that-only-accepts-numerical-t?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can create generic functions/methods:

```
Public Function MyFunction(Of T As IConvertible)(value As T) As T
    'Do something...
End Function

Public Sub MySub(Of T As IConvertible)(value As T)
    'Do something...
End Sub
```

The following types implements the IConvertible interface:

- System.Boolean
- System.Byte
- System.Char
- System.DateTime
- System.DBNull
- System.Decimal
- System.Double
- System.Enum
- System.Int16
- System.Int32
- System.Int64
- System.SByte
- System.Single
- System.String
- System.UInt16
- System.UInt32
- System.UInt64